# Import & Annotation errors in NetBeans 8.2 using Grails 3.3.8 and spring security

Tags: grails, netbeans, spring-security

I'm using NetBeans for the first time to create a Grails application. When the spring security plugin generated the stock User/Role/UserRole domains, NetBeans started throwing errors even though the application was compiling/running without any problem.

For one thing, "import grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria" was throwing an "unable to resolve class" error.

But my favorite error so far is "class grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic is not an annotation in @grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic." This error was appearing in the generated Role.groovy file, but is also appearing in the below Test class:

```
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
class TestClass {

}
```

My grails installation is being managed by sdkman, so I'm wondering if there's some dependency that NetBeans isn't seeing.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzxtc.png)

Comment: Have you installed the **Groovy and Grails** plugin? (**Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins >** Check the entry for **Groovy and Grails >** Click the **Install** button.)

Comment: Yep, I downloaded the NetBeans distro with all the plugins pre-installed. Double-checked to make sure Groovy was still there.

Comment: OK, and you also activated Groovy? (**Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Groovy** tab **>** Click the **Activate** button)

Comment: I don't have an "Activate" button on that tab (I'm on a mac), it just has a space for the Groovy doc and GRAILS_HOME (set to .sdkman/candidates/grails/current).

The plugins does show it as activated.

Comment: To be clear, the Groovy syntax highlighting seems to be working just fine and dandy.

(I added a screenshot to the OP)